# How do Faulty Lamps work?

Tags: terraria

With logic gates, the "state" of the output is decided by the logic gate's condition and when the output changes, the gate sends out a pulse, just like a switch or a lever. Faulty Lamps, on the other hand, seem to change how gates function completely, and I'm not sure I understand all of the differences. I get that it randomly picks one of the lamps below the faulty one, and toggles the output depending on whether it's on or not, but is that all? What happens with lamps above the faulty one? Are the faulty lamp and all of the normal lamps underneath it treated as a single entity? Does the gate type matter at all with faulty lamps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get that it randomly picks one of the lamps below the faulty one, and toggles the output depending on whether it's on or not, but is that all?

Actually it will send signal with probability equal to `Number of active lamps / Number of connected lamps excluding faulty one`. If you have 3 active, one inactive and one faulty lamp, signal will be sent with 75% chance.

> What happens with lamps above the faulty one?

Lamps above faulty one will not count: loop in source code breaks when it encounters faulty lamp.

> Are the faulty lamp and all of the normal lamps underneath it treated as a single entity?

They are treated as part of same machine. Same thing as gate with only normal lamps.

> Does the gate type matter at all with faulty lamps?

No, gate type does not matter.

Comment: The first paragraph is what I said. The second is false as I've placed lamps above faulty ones, and the third is meant to go with the second, asking what happens when you do place a lamp above a faulty lamp.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I couldn't place them. Maybe there was some other factor at work, as ingame testing was minimal, just to prove what I got from studying source code. Lamps above faulty one will not do anything as loop counting lamps and their state stops when it encounters faulty lamp.

Comment: I tried placing normal lamps above faulty ones in a world I'd made in 1.3, but I don't think that should matter. If you could do some testing about that and edit with results, that'd make this answer much better.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer tested, found out that it was my error: place above faulty lamp was blocked. Removed false info from my answer.